# Grouping from dictionary values and elimating duplicates from other groups

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
{'a': ['b','c'],
'b':['e','f'],
'c':['g'],
'h':['m','n']}
```

I want my dictionary to group it according to similarity

this is how I want the dictionary to look after processing:

```
{'a':['b','c','e','f','g'],
'h':['m','n']
}
```

is there any way to do it efficiently? I want to convert this dictionary to a pandas dataframe.

EDIT:

These are actually mapping . The above dictionary means. :

a = b, c
b = e, f

hence,
a = b,c,e,f
similarly,
h = m,n (a different value mapping)

Note : this is purely based on the model which I am designing.

Comment: I think you need to clarify what 'similarity' means. What's the connection between h, m, and n?

Comment: Use a custom function to go through the values and merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know exactly if its the most efficient way to do it (probably isn't) but you can try the following:

```
def merge_entries(input_dict):
    to_delete = set()
    for k,v in input_dict.items():
        if k not in to_delete:
            for x in v:
                if x in input_dict.keys():
                    test[k]+=test[x]
                    to_delete.add(x)

    for i in to_delete:
        del input_dict[i]

    return input_dict

test = {
'a': ['b','c'],
'b':['e','f'],
'c':['g'],
'h':['m','n']
}
print (merge_entries(test))
```

I've interpreted your merge by similarity by if any value of key `x` matches a key `y` in the dictionary, then merge the values of `y` into `x`.

EDIT:

The OP edited the demo dataset to the following:

```
test ={'a': ['b','c'],
'b':['e','f','c'],
'c':['g'],
'h':['m','n'],
'k':['c']}
```

With this case i'am gonna assume that the expected answer is these two groups:

```
[{'g', 'e', 'k', 'f', 'b', 'c', 'a'}, {'h', 'n', 'm'}]
```

I'am also gonna assume that the dictionary format is kinda irrelevant since in the new OP example the dictionary entry `'k':['c']}` is to be merged by the value c to the first group. So I will provide the answer in a list with `n` set entries.

```
def merge_entries2(input_dict):
    results = []
    count = 0
    for k,v in input_dict.items():
        if count == 0: #initial state add a group
            nset=set(v)
            nset.add(k)
            results.append(nset)
            count+=1
        else:
            for i,group in enumerate(results):
                nset = set(v)
                nset.add(k)
                if k in group:
                    results[i] = results[i].union(nset)
                    break
                                        
                else:
                    if len(nset.intersection(group)) > 0:
                        results[i]=results[i].union(nset)
                        break
                        
                    else:
                        results.append(nset)
                        break
                                      
    return results
test ={'a': ['b','c'],
'b':['e','f','c'],
'c':['g'],
'h':['m','n'],
'k':['c']}

print (merge_entries2(test))
```

A quick overview of the script:
When no group is defined, define the first group with the combined value of key value from the first dictionary entry. Then for each other dictionary entry, create a new set with the combined key and value, and check if these set intersects with any existing set, if it does merge them, if not create a new group.

Answer (score 0):

Reformatting the dict,  has side effects but I believe it's clear.

```
d = {'a': ['b', 'c'], 'b': ['e', 'f'], 'c': ['g'], 'h': ['m', 'n']}
for k in list(d.keys()):
    # may have deleted the key,  check..
    if k in d.keys():
        for i in list(d[k]):
            # defined as another key, append and delete..
            if i in d.keys():
                d[k] += d[i]
                del d[i]
# finally construct dataframe dict.  list sizes vary so use {"col":{id:val}} format               
df = pd.DataFrame({k:{i:v for i,v in enumerate(d[k])} for k in d.keys()})
print(d)
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

**output (dict then dataframe)**

```
{'a': ['b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g'], 'h': ['m', 'n']}
 a    h
 b    m
 c    n
 e  NaN
 f  NaN
 g  NaN
```